# How to delete logs size greater than 100 mb in unix

Tags: unix

> I want to delete logs which was greater than 100 mb and it should not return or delete current >month logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using (GNU) find & date:

```
find /path -type f -size +100M -mtime +$(date --date=yesterday +%d) -delete
```

where `/path` is where your logs are located. `-mtime $(date --date=yesterday %d)` means any files last modified *more* than day of month as of yesterday.

Make sure you test this before you use it, say, by using `-ls` to print the files instead of deleting them, or prompt before deleting each file with `-exec rm -i {} \;`.

Answer (score 0):

With find you can use age and size filters and then RM.

find /path/to/files -mtime +30 -size +100M  -exec rm {}

I haven't tested it

Comment: You are better off specifying a directory not a list of files (i.e. leave off '*') otherwise you might hit command line limit.  100c means 100 bytes but op wants 100 MB.